# Is there a way to assign the attribution model for conversions in the Google Query Explorer tool?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to assign the attribution model for conversions in the Google Query Explorer tool?

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

I can't seem to find Multi-channel or attribution models on this tool.

Comment: MCF has it's own reporting API https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3